# Merge after rebasing feature branch in git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I rebase my feature branch on origin/develop to be current on the current state of develop.

```
git checkout feature-X
git rebase origin/develop
```

But when I do this I have to merge immediately after. This makes things messy.

I thought that the whole idea of rebasing was that you could rewrite history (pretend we're working off the tip of origin/develop) and only have to merge when you want to integrate your changes into origin/develop.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** I can't exactly reproduce what I did without lots more git magic but I'm trying to piece together a functioning feature-branch model mostly going off [this gist](https://gist.github.com/17twenty/6733076).

I "git rebase origin/develop" when I'm in my feature branch. That completes but then tells me I have widely diverged from stuff which I then try to fix by doing a push/pull. That creates a merge which I think I don't want.

Comment: Why do you 'have to merge immediately after'? You can continue to work on feature X, only you are now closer to develop branch.

Comment: If I pull/push git forces me to merge.

Comment: What are you `pulling from/pushing to`? Btw, `git pull` means `git fetch` + `git merge`

Comment: Did you update the remote branch after rebasing?

Comment: I thought git pull; git push; was the simple way to always be up to date… so that's what is going wrong.

Comment: @alper can you provide just a bit more detail into your steps and the behaviour you are expecting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming `feature-X` has been branched off `develop`, a better way to do it would be to pull changes from remote onto your local `develop` branch and rebasing `feature-X` from the local branch. That will avoid the merge commit. You can merge feature-X later into your local `develop` and then push it.

If feature-X has been pushed onto the remote, as @crea1 has answered you will have to run this with every rebase from develop

```
git push -f origin feature-x
```

The reason being that the rebase creates entirely new commit ids for the rebased commits. As far as git is concerned they are new commits. That is what is causing your git pull to go for a merge commit. As long as no one is using it, force pushing should be fine.
Also IMHO, it is better if your pull.rebase is set to true in your gitconfig.

Comment: So: autosetuprebase always will make it so that even if I do a git pull; git push; then if it can it will rebase instead of creating a new merge?

Comment: Yes. By default `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`. This will make it `git fetch` + `git rebase`.

Comment: I tried it just now and if I don't do a push --force I can never get in sync again with my published feature branch. I get stuck in an infinite loop of rebase/merge.

Comment: Not doing a push --force after a rebase is counter-productive. You will keep getting duplicate commits.

Comment: That's what I found out the hard way.

Comment: We are adopting rebasing, but I'm still not liking that I have to be sure that no-one is working on my branch, because commits might get lost when someone pushes something just before I do a force

Comment: @Boy instead of `--force`, you can use `--force-with-lease` if that is something you do frequently. `--force-with-lease` will let you force push only if your local branch has the same set of commits as the remote. So if someone has already pushed some other commits, it will prevent you from force pushing.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous but then it will also fail when I rebase as the commits will be different because of rebasing?

Comment: @Boy If a push with `--force-with-lease` was rejected you can pull with `--rebase` and the commits in remote will be properly ordered under the new commits. Depending on how complex the changes are, there may be merge conflicts. In that case it is better to have `rerere` enabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you rebase feature-x on top of origin/develop, you do this on your local repo. This means `feature-x` is still in the state before rebasing in the remote repository. Since they don't have the same ancestor anymore, git will try to merge.

To update the remote branch, you can do a force push.

```
git push origin feature-x --force
```

But beware, if other persons than you are working on `feature-x`, and starts pushing/pulling it can get messy.

I find this link useful for learning about [merging vs rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/workflow-walkthrough)

Comment: That seems to be missing from the guide. If instead of doing this I do git pull then that will lead to stuff I don't want, right?

(No one else is working on the feature-branch and I prefer to keep the changes and updates public for others to try out.)

Comment: Exactly. It will try to merge the remote branch with the local branch, since they are no longer the same. So by doing force push, you are updating the remote references.

Comment: I did read that link. It's one of the 4-5 tabs I have to keep open to be able to even work in git.